# django admin error when adding element to a table (Please correct the errors below)

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms

I've spend the whole day on an error tell by django admin = Please correct the error bellow) when saving data
[image]

The thing is i don't get any other indication about the error and i have no idea how to solve the problem

models.py

```
class meeting(models.Model):
time = models.DateTimeField()
capacity = models.CharField(max_length=25, default=0)
USERNAME_FIELD = 'time'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['time']
```

admin.py

```
class MeetingAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
list_display = ('time', 'capacity')
list_filter = ('time', 'capacity')
fieldsets = (
    (None, {'fields': ('time', 'capacity')}),
)

add_fieldsets = (
    (None, {
        'classes': ('time', 'capacity'),
        'fields': ('time', 'capacity'),
    }),
)

search_fields = ('time',)
ordering = ('time',)
filter_horizontal = ()
```

```
    admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
admin.site.register(meeting, MeetingAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're extending BaseUserAdmin which is certainly not ok. You should extend ModelAdmin instead.

```
from django.contrib import admin

class MeetingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
```